# File too large (limit of 2097152 bytes) when upload modules in Prestashop

Tags: e-commerce, prestashop-1.6

i faced File too large (limit of 2097152 bytes). in Prestashop when i was install a modules. and also i found when i was upload Themes.
Pls help me how to fixed it.

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be fixed by changing the following properties in your `php.ini` file on the webserver.

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

By default, both of these properties are set to 2M, which is the reason for your error, you are trying to upload a file larger then this limit.

To locate your `php.ini` file, create a new *.php* file with the following contents

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

Navigate to this page in your web browser and it will output all info about the running server. Included in this output will be the directory of said file.

Comment: May i know where php.ini is exit ?

Comment: and restart apache for it to take effect